# parallax dentro de div

Tags: html, css

Quiero aplicar un efecto `parallax` dentro del `div` para que cuando pase el texto me cambie la imagen pero la segunda imagen me la coloca fuera del `div` padre

```css
html, body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
#article{
    background-color: rgb(126,230,222, 0);
    padding: 0;
    height: 70%;
    width: 55%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0 0 10px;
}

   
.text {
   background-color: aqua;
   height: 15%;
    width: 100%;
}
#imagen1{ 
    background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/wi2SHGD.jpg");
 height:100%;
 background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 position: relative;
   
}

    

#imagen2{ 
    background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/kxnzTtA.jpg");
 height:100%;
 background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 position: relative;
   
}
```

```html
        <div id="article">
            <div id="imagen1">

                <div class="text">
                    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                </div> <!-- If you want text inside the container --> 
            </div>
            <div id="imagen2">

                <div class="text">
                    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                </div> <!-- If you want text inside the container --> 
            </div>
           

        </div>
```

Comment: Por favor sube tus imágenes a algún banco de imágenes gratuito y cambia tus rutas por la url para poderlas visualizar

Comment: me podrías decir algún banco ?

Comment: Podrías mirar [este](https://es.imgbb.com/)

Comment: gracias ya están las imágenes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según lo que entiendo que quieres hacer, podrías resolverlo de la siguiente manera:

```css
html, body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
#article{
    background-color: rgb(126,230,222, 0);
    padding: 0;
    height: 70%;
    width: 55%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0 0 10px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

   
.text {
   background-color: aqua;
   height: 15%;
    width: 100%;
}
#imagen1{ 
    background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/wi2SHGD.jpg");
 height:100%;
 background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 position: relative;
   
}

    

#imagen2{ 
    background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/kxnzTtA.jpg");
 height:100%;
 background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 position: relative;
   
}
```

```html
        <div id="article">
            <div id="imagen1">

                <div class="text">
                    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                </div> <!-- If you want text inside the container --> 
            </div>
            <div id="imagen2">

                <div class="text">
                    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                </div> <!-- If you want text inside the container --> 
            </div>
           

        </div>
```

Solo debes controlar el atributo `overflow` de tu `div#article` para que el efecto `parallax` se vea de la forma que lo esperas.

Comment: si era eso lo que quería gracias. ¿la barra de scrool se puede ocultar?

Comment: Que yo sepa no, por que hay que darle si o si overflow: auto para que pueda existir el scroll, ya podrías darle estilos al scroll para hacer la barra mas pequeña al punto de casi no verse, saludos !